# Navigate to another page when orientation changed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I will explain what I'm trying to do on following instance:

I have two pages - MainPage.xaml (orientation Portrait) and LandscapeLeft.xaml (orientation LandscapeLeft).

I want to navigate from `MainPage.xaml` to `LandscapeLeft.xaml` when user rotate phone on Lanscape position.

I've done as follows:

XAML:

```
   SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
```

code behind:

```
   protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       switch (e.Orientation)
       {
           case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
               NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LandscapeLeft.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
               break;
       }
       base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
   }
```

When I rotate phone from PortraitUp to LandscapeLeft position that what happens:
Firstly, content of MainPage.xaml rotates landscape and just then LandscapeLeft.xaml loads.

What I want to do is to eliminate process of content rotation of MainPage.xaml. It doesn't look good and affects performance. Simply, when I rotate the phone I want LandscapeLeft.xaml to be loaded
without previous change of content orientation of MainPage.xaml.

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about putting your contents in a frame.
When orientation event fires, change the frame contents instead of navigating to a different page.

```
 ...
         case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
         FrmContents= new LandscapeLeft();
 ...
```

This should sort out your performance issues.

Comment: is the frame a silverlight control?

Comment: @JohnnyDropTables What is FrmContents?

Answer (score 3):

Just put all the functionality on one page and then alter what is shown based on the orientation.

Comment: As  I  have  written  to  Stuart,  I have too many controls on pages to
handle them by visibility.

Comment: @Maku sorry should have been clearer. I would never recommend changing the visibility of each item on a page individually.

Answer (score 2):

From a "user" perspective, I don't think you should use Navigation to achieve this effect.

Navigation is really closely tied to the Back button - so it's not something a user normally expects to also be tied to the device orientation as well.

Things you could probably do are:

- consider hosting both the portrait and the landscape controls in the mainpage.xaml - just change the "visibility" of the 2 controls depending on the orientation.
- if possible consider using the same controls for both orientation - but with appropriate layout changes for the 2 orientations.

I've written apps that support both orientations - they seem to perform really well - what performance issues are you seeing?

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  suggestions.  Normally,  I would do as you have
written  above  but I have too many controls on pages to handle them by
visibility property.

Comment: Can't you put them all inside two panels and then change the visibility of each of those parent panels? OR can't you just bind each individual visibility to some shared property?

Comment: Of course it can be done. You are absolutely right. Nevertheless, it is easier for me to design different orientation pages (with completely various content) separately. Anyway, thank you for your advises!