# Is any method similar to OnOrientationChanged?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, orientation

Is there a method like `protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)` which works when `SupportedOrientations="Portrait"` ?

What I'm trying to do is to implement some gestures like:

- User rotates phone to landscape left position and some code is executed
- User rotates phone to landscape right position and some another code is executed

My app is PortraitUp orientated. When I set `SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"` the content starts to rotate.

Or perhaps should I use accelerometer to handle phone position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're after the accelerometer, there are few helpers available on codeplex which may give you a leg up:

http://accelerometer.codeplex.com/ - visual aid for understanding what's going on with the accelerometer
http://phone7actionpack.codeplex.com/ - includes a change visual state behavior when the phone rotates.

Comment: As you posted, accelerometer was the only reasonable solution. Fortunately, it is easy to handle. Thank you for links. For me it was really helpful to see Microsoft's [accelerometer sample.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're after a "OnOrientationChangedToLandscapeLeft" type event (and similar).
This doesn't exist but you can create this yourself with what does exist.

Within the `OnOrientaionChanged` event you can detect which way the screen is rotated by checking the `e` argument and then executing relevant code accordingly.
Something like:

```
if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
{
    // Do whatever you want to here
}
else if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
{
    // Do something else here
}
else
...
```

Comment: The   only   problem  is  that  `OnOrientaionChanged`  fires  when  page orientation  is  changed.  My  app is `SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="PortraitUp"`  and  `OnOrientationChanged`  never  starts.  I don't  want  to  change `SupportedOrientations` to `"PortraitOrLandscape"` because   content   starts   to   rotate   and that doesn't look good, especially phone rotation suppose to be a gesture.

Comment: @Maku I have created an app which always appear to be in portrait but uses the above to detct orientation changed internally. It makes everything still look like it did in portrait by using RotationTransforms. NOt the most elegant of solutions but it works.

Comment: You just answered my... [another question!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116687/navigate-to-another-page-when-orientation-changed) Thank you so much for your contribution!