# Windows Phone page navigation on orientation changed - page view problems

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, navigation, orientation

I have three xaml pages, e.g. MainPage.xaml(empty), PageOne.xaml and PageTwo.xaml.
After loading of MainPage I load the contents of PageOne.xaml.
What I want to achieve is navigate from PageOne to PageTwo when orientation changes.

I have implemented this successfully using this thread - [Navigate to another page when orientation changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116687/navigate-to-another-page-when-orientation-changed) by changing the content in the frame eliminating the process of content rotation:(((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual)).Content = new PageOne();

The problem is:
When Application is fired on Portrait mode PageOne is shows in portrait mode as expected. But when I rotate the phone to landscape, MainPage loads the contents of PageTwo as expected but in **portrait mode**. I want it to load on **landscape mode**.

I have set SupportedOrientations in XAML(tried in code-behind too) to Portrait for PageOne and to Landscape for PageTwo, but that doesn't help. I guess the phone just doesn't detect orientation change when content is loaded dynamically. Any suggestions?

Using NavigationService just doesn't look good - at first page rotates and then navigates.

I also want to achieve rotation animation between pages, but i think that is not possible in my case.

Here is some code in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void PageOrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
       if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
       {
                (((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual)).Content = new PageOne();
       }
       else
       {
                (((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual)).Content = new PageTwo();
       }
}
```

PageTwo loads when MainPage is in landscape mode, but is shown like Portrait mode. As if I load only PageTwo in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It Should work

```
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(
object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
            {
                //Load Data for Portrait PageOrientation
            }
            else
            {
                //Load Data for Landscape PageOrientation
            }
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 

Page loads when orientation changed like I described but it is loaded as if I am holding the phone in portrait mode.